# JQuery Mobile: can't update google map

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, cordova

We have a location based app in (Phone Gap using JQuery Mobile) which is supposed to load google map with a marker showing the position of the place. After the first load the map doesn't refresh. I want to show different locations based on the address.

The live doesn't seem to get unbinded even if I use die.

Here is the code.

```js
function loadMap(indexClicked){
  var offerPosition = getLatAndLong(indexClicked);
  var centerSettings = { 'center': offerPosition, 'zoom': 10 };
  initMap(centerSettings,indexClicked);
  refreshMap();
}

function initMap(centerSettings,indexClicked){
  $('#load-map').live('pageshow', function() {
    $('#map-canvas').gmap({'center': centerSettings.center, 'zoom': centerSettings.zoom, 'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function() {
        var self = this;
        self.addMarker({'position': this.get('map').getCenter() }).click(function() {
            self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': showAdrressInMap(indexClicked) }, this);
        });
    }});
  });
}

function refreshMap(){
  $('#load-map').live('pageshow', function() {
    $('#map-canvas').gmap('refresh');
  });
}
```

The function loadMap is called on every button clicked.

**PS**: After the first load the map seems to get cached and returns the same address every time. When clicking on the marker it refreshes address in the tooltip but the postion seems to be same. I am using jquery mobile 1.0 with phone gap 1.3.0 along with jquery.ui.map.js, jquery.ui.map.services.js, jquery.ui.map.extensions.js and modernizr.min.js

Comment: Having same problem 'When clicking on the marker it refreshes address in the tooltip but the postion seems to be same.' Please provide answer...

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following approach in order to clear the markers, add new markers and set dynamically the center position of the jQuery-ui-map.

```
//clear all markers
$('#map_canvas').gmap('clear', 'markers');

// add a new marker
var $marker = $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {id: i, 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(cityList[i][1], cityList[i][2]), title: cityList[i][0]});

// on marker click show the description
$marker.click(function() {
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': cityList[this.id][0]}, this);
});

// update the map's center position             
$("#map_canvas").gmap("get", "map").panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(cityList[i][1], cityList[i][2]));
```

> According the [Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference), the `panTo` method pans the map by the minimum amount necessary to contain the given LatLngBounds. It makes no guarantee where on the map the bounds will be, except that as much of the bounds as possible will be visible. The bounds will be positioned inside the area bounded by the map type and navigation (pan, zoom, and Street View) controls, if they are present on the map. If the bounds is larger than the map, the map will be shifted to include the northwest corner of the bounds. If the change in the map's position is less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated.

Below you can find a sample. If you press the Chicago button a marker will be added and map's center position will be updated to the Chicago

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps - Google maps jQuery plugin</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/min/jquery.ui.map.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var mobileDemo = { 'center': '41,-87', 'zoom': 7 },
                cityList = [
                    ['Chicago', 41.850033,-87.6500523, 1],
                    ['Kentucki', 37.735377,-86.572266, 2]
                ];

            function initialize()
            {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': mobileDemo.center, 'zoom': mobileDemo.zoom, 'disableDefaultUI':false });
            }

            function addMarker(i)
            {
                //clear all markers
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('clear', 'markers');

                // add a new marker
                var $marker = $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {id: i, 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(cityList[i][1], cityList[i][2]), title: cityList[i][0]});

                // on marker click show the description
                $marker.click(function() {
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': cityList[this.id][0]}, this);
                });

                // set the map's center position
                $("#map_canvas").gmap("get", "map").panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(cityList[i][1], cityList[i][2]));
            }

            $(document).on("pageinit", "#basic-map", function() {
                initialize();
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.add-marker', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                addMarker(this.id);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="basic-map" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">jQuery mobile with Google maps v3</a> examples</h1>
                <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" id="0" class="add-marker" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Chicago</a>
                <a href="#" id="1" class="add-marker" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Kentucki</a>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I had to use $('#map_canvas').gmap('destroy') and recreated it with new marker location and it worked. clearing old markers and setting up was not working....